# Dealing with RPC when doing multiple GWT modules

Tags: gwt

I did some refactoring of my gwt application, and make it multiple modules (i.e. multiple *.gwt.xml and EntryPoint)

Everything seems to work fine, except for the RPC. Since I refactored the application, from a single `mygwtapp.gwt.xml` into multiple gwt.xml files:

```
main.gwt.xml
user.gwt.xml
login.gwt.xml
```

and so on...

I had to change the servlet mapping URL-pattern from:

```
/mygwtapp/someRPC
```

into `/main/someRPC` to make sure that RPC's will work for the main module. It works for the main module but not for the other modules. As each module is excepting to have RPC call relative to its module name like `/user/someRPC`

What is the work-around for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to options, either to use setServiceEntryPoint() and set the absolute path ("/main/someRpc") or use  @RemoteServiceRelativePath but set the path to ("../main/someRpc") :)

Comment: what stops you from trying? :)

Comment: Lying in my bed with a tablet?

Comment: I does work. Nice trick. The only downside is that now IDEA complains about wrong url pattern in web.xml. Also, GWT complains while compiling that there are missing mappings. I think I'll stick with multiple `<url-pattern>` solution.

Comment: yeah, that's annoying, maybe it can be qualified as an IDEA bug.  I prefer your way of listing multiple url-pattern elements.

Comment: GWT warnings are more annoying: we use a build system and warnings are never good, because they can mislead som non-GWT people.

Answer (score 2):

Put rpc code in a shared dir, refer to it via `source` directive in you module descriptor, then make multiple mappings to the same servlet in your ’web.xml`.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SomeServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/moduleOne/rpc/SomeService</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/moduleTwo/rpc/SomeService</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/moduleThree/rpc/SomeService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```