# Cannot apply CSS through GWT WindowBuilder editor for a multiple modules/Entrypoint application

Tags: gwt

I usually use GWT WindowBuilder editor to design my GWT application UI, however I refactored my application to implement multiple modules/EntryPoint as described in my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834946/dealing-with-rpc-when-doing-multiple-gwt-modules)

Now I am getting  this error "There are no CSS files referenced from modules HTML." when I click the CSS button from the Property Editor of the WindowBuilder editor.

Is there any way to fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple,

I created a package like this:

com.mycompany.css

and put the CSS there and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If your web application files are in war folder. Make a subdirectory war/css and put your css files there. Then go to *your-module.xml* configuration file and declare this folder as public:

```
<public path="css" />
```

Now reload the Windows Builder Design View and automatically Windows Builder will map your css files.